# getChildrenCategories not working in magento, sort category by position in admin

Tags: magento

i won't to sort categories in frontend as in admin if i use getChildren then it will not sort categories as in admin but if i use getChildrenCategories then no result

```
  <?php

$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(74)->getChildren();

$catIds = explode(',',$cats);

$categories = array();
foreach($catIds as $catId) {
     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);



    $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
        'url' => $category->getUrl(),
        'img' => $category->getImageUrl()
    );
}

ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ordered collection. See below example:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(74);

$collection = $category->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
    ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
    ->setOrder('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC);
```

You can then loop through the collection to render the items.